# How to make href's work as expected

Tags: url

I have two questions here, that I thought there were already asked, but I could not find anything related.

Let's suppose I have the following URL:

`http://www.domain.com/folder/page`

And I have an anchor like this:

```
<a href="page2.php">Page2</a>
```

**First:** 
Of course when it is clicked, it will navigate to

`http://www.domain.com/folder/page2`

But if the user has this URL:

`http://www.domain.com/folder/page/` <-- Note the last slash

Then the anchor will navigate to:

`http://www.domain.com/folder/page/page2`

The first question is:

**How can I avoid this?**

And the second question would be:

**How to always do this?**

I mean that even if the url ends with a slash or not, navigate to:

`http://www.domain.com/folder/page/page2`

I know I can do this with javascript, but the idea is to keep using the href without using javascript in every case this happens. I also know I can use relative urls starting with `/` to referrer the root, but I can't in this case because the url has some IDs in the middle that may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you have two URLs that resolve to the same resource.

Pick one of them to be canonical and redirect from the other one two it using HTTP.

Failing that, use root relative URIs:

```
href="/folder/page2"
```

Comment: and the second one? I mean if I am at `domain.com/page` then navigate to `domain.com/page/page2`. Is there any way?

Comment: yes.. but without using the root relative url? I could be at something like `domain.com/page/45243543`and want to navigate to `domain.com/page/45243543/edit`

Comment: Then use HTTP redirects to always push browsers to the canonical URL.